# Como fundir várias planilhas de Excel em uma só?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Eu tenho um conjunto de planilhas (por exemplo, suponha que se chamem file01.xls, file02.xls, file03.xls etc.), todas com as mesmas colunas na aba Sheet1 e com as demais abas vazias.
Como faço para unir essas planilhas em uma só sem precisar abrir, copiar e colar uma por uma?

Um exemplo para melhor ilustração. Suponha que file01.xls contenha:

```
|    |   A    |      B       |
|----|--------|--------------|
| 1  | NOME   | RG           |
| 2  | João   | 12.345.678-9 |
| 3  | José   | 11.111.111-1 |
| 4  | Maria  | 12.121.212-1 |
```

que file02.xls contenha:

```
|    |    A    |       B       |
|----|---------|---------------|
| 1  | NOME    | RG            |
| 2  | Luís    | 55.555.555-5  |
| 3  | Carlos  | 98.765.432-1  |
| 4  | Ana     | 22.333.444-5  |
```

e que file03.xls contenha:

```
|    |    A    |       B        |
|----|---------|----------------|
| 1  | NOME    | RG             |
| 2  | Marcos  | 12.321.234-3   |
| 3  | Edna    | 98.765.678-9   |
| 4  | Ida     | 99.888.777-6   |
```

O que eu quero obter é um file_agregado.xls que contenha:

```
|     |    A    |       B        |
|-----|---------|----------------|
|  1  | NOME    | RG             |
|  2  | João    | 12.345.678-9   |
|  3  | José    | 11.111.111-1   |
|  4  | Maria   | 12.121.212-1   |
|  5  | Luís    | 55.555.555-5   |
|  6  | Carlos  | 98.765.432-1   |
|  7  | Ana     | 22.333.444-5   |
|  8  | Marcos  | 12.321.234-3   |
|  9  | Edna    | 98.765.678-9   |
| 10  | Ida     | 99.888.777-6   |
```

Comment: De forma fácil, tem esse suplemento aqui https://www.ablebits.com/excel-addins.php Ou você pode usar Power Query: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-data-from-multiple-data-sources-Power-Query-70cfe661-5a2a-4d9d-a4fe-586cc7878c7d

Comment: @Marcelo essa união é única ou é algo que precises fazer diariamente.

Comment: Somente fórmula do Excel ou você também utiliza VBA?

Comment: R. Galamba, essa é uma união que eu faço mensalmente. Faço na base do copiar e colar, mas algo que a automatizasse seria bem vindo.

Comment: danieltakeshi, eu utilizo VBA mas algo mais simples seria preferível.

Comment: Em tempo: eu uso R e tentei fazer um programa para automatizar essa junção, mas apareceu uma mensagem de erro que eu não faço a menor idéia de o que signifique ou como corrigir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível com a utilização de **VBA**

**Código:**

- Seleciona os arquivos que deseja fundir
- Copia o título somente do primeiro arquivo.
- Copia da coluna A até a última coluna (no caso do exemplo "B"), se a planilha se chamar "Sheet1"
- Cola na planilha Dados

Utiliza a função `SheetKiller()` para remover uma planilha, caso ela exista.

```
'https://professor-excel.com/merge-excel-files-combine-workbooks-one-file/
Sub FundirPastasDeTrabalhoExcel()
    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Long, UltimaLinhaFonte As Long, UltimaLinhaDestino As Long, k As Long
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet, dados As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Seleção de arquivos
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

    'Cria planilha de dados
    SheetKiller ("Dados")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Dados"
    Set dados = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados")

    'Loop nos arquivos selecionados
    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count

        'Abre as Pastas de Trabalho Excel
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i))

        'Loop em cada planilha do arquivo (pasta de trabalho) aberto
        For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
            'Se o nome da planilha é "Sheet1"
            With tempWorkSheet
                If .Name = "Sheet1" Then
                    UltimaLinhaFonte = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    UltimaLinhaDestino = dados.Cells(dados.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    UltimaColuna = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
                    'Verifica se é a primeira planilha para copiar o título
                    If i = 1 Then
                        k = 0
                    Else
                       k = 1
                    End If
                    'Copia e cola valores
                    .Range(.Cells(1 + k, "A"), .Cells(UltimaLinhaFonte, UltimaColuna)).Copy
                    dados.Range("A" & UltimaLinhaDestino + k).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
                End If
            End With
        Next tempWorkSheet

        'Fecha a Pasta de Trabalho
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
    'Deleta a Planilha temporária para remover possíveis erros na função SheetKiller
    SheetKiller ("tempSheetKiller")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Public Function SheetKiller(Name As String)
    'Remove Planilha
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If k = 1 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "tempSheetKiller"
        k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    End If
    For i = k To 1 Step -1
        t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        If t = Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Testei mas não funcionou. A macro parou na linha

.Range(.Cells(1 + k, "A"), .Cells(UltimaLinhaFonte, UltimaColuna)).Copy

e apareceu om quadrinho com a mensagem de erro:
Erro em tempo de execução '1004':
Erro de definição de aplicativo ou definição de objeto

Comment: Alterei a resposta, erro de digitação. Troque de `UltimaColuna = LastColumn =  .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column` para `UltimaColuna = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column`

Comment: Funcionou mas ficou aparecendo a janelinha com a mensagem "Há muita informação na Área de transferência. Deseja poder colar essa informações em outro programa?".   Tem como automatizar uma resposta Não para todas as aparições dessa janela?

Comment: Tem como desabilitar as notificações. Com `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` no início do código e `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` no fim, para reabilitar.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se for permitido, gostaria de solicitar um adendo: as planilhas que eu mesclo são sempre as mesmas, que eu recebo periodicamente de outra pessoa. Por isso, seria muito mais fácil se eu pudesse listá-las diretamente no código em vez de selecionar na janela. Isso é possível?

Comment: Isto é questão de outra pergunta, mas pesquise antes.